# ContentObserver does not notify on above API 17

Tags: android, contentobserver

I have a ContentObserver on my application to check when a contact is edited, I have implemented it with the following code, it works on devices with lower android API than 17 but not 17 and higher.

```
observer = new MyContentObserver();
getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, true, observer);


private class MyContentObserver extends ContentObserver
{
    public MyContentObserver()
    {
        super(null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onChange(boolean selfChange)
    {
        super.onChange(selfChange);
        cache.clearCache();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the `MyContentObserver` class.

Comment: I have edited my post and added MyContentObserver class. It works great on my API 16 phone but not on phones with newer API. I usually use System.out.println to check if it is fired the onChange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem is that newer API levels utilize an overload of the `onChange()` method that takes two parameters: a `boolean` and a `Uri`. Try changing your code as follows:

```
private class MyContentObserver extends ContentObserver
{ 
    public MyContentObserver() 
    { 
        super(null); 
    } 

    @Override 
    public void onChange(boolean selfChange)
    {  
        onChange(selfChange, null); 
    }

    @Override
    public void onChange(boolean selfChange, Uri uri)
    {
        cache.clearCache();
    } 
}
```

You could call `cache.clearCache();` in both methods directly, but this way will allow any possible future modifications to be made in just one place. Also, the calls to `super.onChange()` are unnecessary, as the overridden methods are empty in the super class.

Comment: This works, but there is another problem. When the user clicks the back button and my app is destroyed the contentobserver is destroyed too. I need contentobserver to be alive everytime and clear the cache when a contact is edited so it will show updated images of contacts in my ListView. Will this consume to much memory and is there any other method to have updated listview with photo of contacts.

Comment: You're gonna need to post a new question for that. But just to give you an idea of the info you need to provide in that question: By "alive everytime", do you mean running constantly? Is this "cache" an object in your app? If your ListView shows only when your app runs, why don't you just update on startup, and have your Observer monitoring during runtime? If you really do need this Observer to run constantly, you'll need a Service. But I would think updating when the app starts should be sufficient.

Comment: Thanks for your fast response. "cache" is an object "DiskLruImageCache", it saves images of contacts. On database I have some phone numbers and from them I get the name and image if that phone number is registered on that phone. Then on my listview I display name, number and image of those contacts. If I do not use cache scrolling is really slow. For that reason I wanted to cache images and clear the cache only when a contact on phone is edited. But when my app is destroyed so it is my contentobserver so it does not notify my app to clear cache.

Comment: Could you just rebuild the cache each time on startup? I don't know how long it takes, but I think an extra second to load is worth smooth scrolling. If that won't work, though, then you'll wanna use a Service, which could also rebuild the cache in the background when it gets cleared. Probably a nicer  from a user-experience perspective, and I don't imagine it would drain too much in the way of resources.

Comment: I can but I do not like how it takes time at the beginning to load all images. Thanks a lot for your suggestion I will try to use a service, if it takes to much RAM I will go with the rebuilding cache each time on start-up.